# how to get all Radio Button answer values

Tags: android, mysql, json

I'm getting Radio Button selected value, but the last question answer value is not getting through. How do I get all question answer values? I think my second IF condition is true when the last question is selected.
How to get all `RadioButton` values?

```
try {
    jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string);
    jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
    count++;
    if(jsonArray.length()!=0) {
      if(jsonArray.length()==count){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No More Questions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Summary.class);
        ArrayList<String> Result=new ArrayList<String>();
        Result.add(0,String.valueOf(score));
        Result.add(1,String.valueOf(wrong));
        Result.add(2,String.valueOf(unanswer));
        Result.add(3,String.valueOf(correct));
        intent.putExtra("Result",Result);
        intent.putExtra("Questions",(Ques));
        intent.putExtra("urAnswer",urans);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
      }


      JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
      Ques = JO.getString("QuestionText");
      Options = JO.getString("Options").split("##");
      ans = Integer.parseInt(JO.getString("CorrectAnswer"));
      RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
      if (answer == null) {
        i = 5;
      } else {
        if (answer.equals(r1)) {
          i = 1;
          Answers.add(r1.getText().toString());
        } else if (answer.equals(r2)) {
          i = 2;
          Answers.add(r1.getText().toString());
        } else if (answer.equals(r3)) {
          i = 3;
          Answers.add(r1.getText().toString());
        } else if (answer.equals(r4)) {
          i = 4;
          Answers.add(r1.getText().toString());
        }
      }
      urans = urans + i;
      if (i == 5) {
        score = score;
        unanswer++;
      } else if (i == ans) {
        score++;
        correct++;
      } else if (!(i == ans)) {
        score = score - 0.25;
        wrong++;
      }
      countDownTimer2.start();
      ques.setText(" Question. No.(" + (QuestionNo + count + 1) + ").\n " + Ques);
      r1.setText(Options[0]);
      r2.setText(Options[1]);
      r3.setText(Options[2]);
      r4.setText(Options[3]);
      rgroup.clearCheck();
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: for example my Question is 7 but only 6 Question value is get ....

Comment: last Question value Skip